# how to search for the words containing a specific number of letters

Tags: c#, listbox

I have list box contains a number of words so, I want to search for the words containing a specific number of letters 
for example: searching for "ea." the result of the search should be (admire-read-era)

```
            string txt=scatt_letter.Text;
            foreach (string item in listBox1.Items)
            {
                string item1 = item.ToLower();
                for (int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < item1.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (txt[i] == item1[j])

                            listBox2.Items.Add(item);      
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Some code examples? what did go wrong?

Comment: You can use regular expression, but as already mentioned, pls tell us what you have done so far.

Comment: I have tried the above code. The results shown is words with (e) or (a) only. What I expect is getting words with (e) and (a) in the same word.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all word with length 10 from a List of strings you can do:

```
    using System.Linq;


    var wordsWithLength10 = listBox1.Items.Where(item => item.Length == 10).ToList();
```

does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.